# My php does not render an xml output; But renders correctly on a browser

Tags: php, xml, drupal-7

I am using a `drupal_http_request` to an xml string from another web site I am currently trying to figure out how to grab this as an xml it does not seem to be working but when I run the exact same url in a browser it gives me back the information in xml format any ideas on how to do this Thought if I put something in like `$headers = array("Content-Type: text/xml")` when I execute `$http_contents = drupal_http_request($url, $headers = array("Content-Type: text/xml"));` it would give me the data in an xml format but it is not any ideas thanks in advance Below is my code

```
<form method="post">
<p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" /><br />
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send it!"></p>
</form>

<?php

   if($_POST)
   {


      $url = "https://pdb-services-beta.nipr.com/pdb-xml-reports/hitlist_xml.cgi?customer_number=testlogin&pin_number=testpin&report_type=1";
      $url = $url . "&name_last=" . $_POST['lastname'] ."&name_first=". $_POST['firstname'];

      $result = grabData($url);
      $xml=simplexml_load_file("$result.xml");
      $nipr_id = $xml->NPN;

      echo "Agent  " . $_POST['firstname'] . " " . $_POST['lastname'] . " Id is:".  $nipr_id  . "<br />\n";
   }
?>

<?php

function grabData($url)
{

$http_contents = drupal_http_request($url);
    if (!isset($http_contents->data)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot get contents from the URL");
    }

    if($replace_special_characters)
        $http_contents_data = str_replace('&','&amp;', $http_contents->data);
    else
        $http_contents_data = $http_contents->data;

    $xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
    xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $http_contents_data, $result);
    xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
    echo "Display http_contents_data " . $http_contents_data .  "<br />\n";
    echo "Display result " . $result .  "<br />\n";
    return $result;

}

?>
```

here is what I am receiving

```
LISTsamplelastname, samplefirstname samplemiddlenamesampleidsampleidstateDOB
```

and when I run the url through the browser I get this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<HITLIST> 
   <TRANSACTION_TYPE> 
     <TYPE>
         LIST
     </TYPE> 
   </TRANSACTION_TYPE> 
   <INDIVIDUAL>
        <NAME>
             samplelastname, samplefirstname samplemiddlename
        </NAME>      
        <ID_ENTITY>
             sampleid
        </ID_ENTITY>
        <NPN>
            sampleid
        </NPN>
        <STATE_‌​RESIDENT>
         state
        </STATE_RESIDENT>
        <DATE_BIRTH>
         dob
        </DATE_BIRTH>
  </INDIVIDUAL> 
  <INDIVIDUAL>
  </INDIVIDUAL>
```

With the help of Supdley and My fellow worker John Salevetti I found the solution. Merely wrap the xml contents in  htmlspecialchars  the xml now displays

Comment: it's not giving you XML as you want it to, but what *does* it give you? what format is it giving you the data in?

Comment: please edit the question to include that data; it's not really readable in the comment. Also, please state precisely how it differs from what you are expecting.

Comment: Did so its up with the code now

Comment: Are you absolutely *certain* that you're getting plain text without any XML? The code seems to be very confused. `$feed` is populated but never used; `$replace_special_characters` is used but never populated; `$result = grabData()` outputs an array (the output of `xml_parse_into_struct()`), but then you seem to be trying to use `$result` as a string....? I don't know what's going on there, but it looks very confused. Where are you looking at the result of the http call? Are you sure it doesn't include the XML tags? Have you done 'view source' as well?

Comment: sorry the code above was not updated please take a look now it should be less confusing

Comment: So you're doing `echo "Display http_contents_data " . $http_contents_data .  "<br />\n";` and not seeing any XML tags.... heh. I'd be willing to bet that if you **VIEW SOURCE**, you'll see that all the XML tags are there; they're just not being displayed by the browser because it's in HTML mode and is treating those xml tags as unknown HTML tags. VIEW THE SOURCE. It will be there.

Comment: Yup and the actual solution was to wrap it in htmlspecialchars thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was wrapping the xml content in question in a htmlspecialchars command this will override the suppression of non-html characters on the page. Would like to send a shoutout to Spudley who looked at this code and reminded me of the nonhtml character suppression Thanks Spudley for helping me not to go too far down that rabbit hole!

this was the original line ....

```
echo "Display http_contents_data " . $http_contents_data .  "<br />\n";
```

and this is the modified line......

```
echo "Display http_contents_data " . htmlspecialchars($http_contents_data) .  "<br />\n";
```